# Spark number of executor decision

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can we process 1tb of data  using spark with 2 executors having 5 gb of memory each.if not how many executors are required, Assuming we don't have any time constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult question without looking at your data and code.
If you're ingesting raw files of 1TB without any caching then it MAY be possible with 5GB memory, but it will take very very long time as the parallelization is limited with only 2 executors unless you have multiple cores. Also, it depends wther you're asking for compressed 1GB or raw text files.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Functionality of my code is reading 1 tb  json files from hdfs, adding a column, filtering and writing back to hdfs

Comment: Most likely you'll be able to do, but note that the process will take longer time to finish. When you provide 5GB, it actually get 2.5GB, but it depends on your spark configurations. Also, if files are small in size, use more executor-cores if possible.

Comment: welcome! let me know if it works for you or if you get any other error and don't forget to vote.